# Access properties in usercontrol

Tags: user-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I created a usercontrol with 2 properties :

- Url : image url (string)
- Color : color to tint the image (System.Windows.Media.Color)

There is my XAML to call the usercontrol :

```
<myUserControl:MyImageTint Url="Assets/Images/decoration.png" Color="{Binding ImageColor}"/>
```

There is my code behind in the usercontrol

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Url", typeof(string), typeof(MyImageTint), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(MyImageTint), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Url
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(UrlProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ColorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to use this properties to tinted my image.
In the Url setter I can set my image url and display it. But I can't use the color to tint the image. The property is null.

How can I use this property in the same function ?

Answer (score 0):

I tinted my image in the usercontrol Loaded event, like this and I can use my properties

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TintMyImage(Url, Color);
}
```

Is it the best way ?